# A piece of seemingly innocent swift code taking a long time to compile. Bug?

Tags: ios, swift, compilation

My swift project does not compile:

[image]

The progress bar just stays there for a looooooong time. At first, I thought it is caused by the dictionary literal bug. But no, it isn't.

After a long time of removing code to see if it compiles, I finally found out where the problem is. This exact piece of code is causing the compiler to freak out!

```
if let desc = (operation as? CustomStringConvertible)?.description {
    helpString += "<p>\(NSLocalizedString(desc, comment: ""))</p>"
}
```

No dictionary/tuple/array literals, just a simple cast and optional binding. This causes the whole thing to be stuck!

To reporduce this, create a test project or something. Add a new file to the project and add this code to the file:

```
import UIKit

protocol Operation {
    var operationName: String { get }
    var operationAvailableInputs: [(name: String, desc: String)] { get }
    var operationRejectFloatingPoint: Bool { get }
    var operationImage: UIImage? { get }

    func calculate (inputs: [String: Double]) -> [(name: String, from: String, result: String)]?
}

class OperationViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    var operation: Operation!


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showOperationHelp" {
            let vc: UIViewController = segue.destinationViewController
            var helpString: String = "<h1>\(NSLocalizedString(operation.operationName, comment: ""))</h1>"

            if let desc = (operation as? CustomStringConvertible)?.description {
                helpString += "<p>\(NSLocalizedString(desc, comment: ""))</p>"
            }

            helpString += "<ul>"

            for (name, desc) in operation.operationAvailableInputs {
                helpString += "<li>\(name): \(NSLocalizedString(desc, comment: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("ANGLE_MEASURE", withString: NSLocalizedString("Radians", comment: "")))</li>"
            }
            helpString += "</ul>"
            helpString += operation.operationRejectFloatingPoint ? NSLocalizedString("This operation accepts integers ONLY. Other forms of input will be ignored", comment: "") : ""
        } else if segue.identifier == "showResults" {
        }
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Only 36 lines of code. Now, cmd + B to build the project and you will see that compilation is stuck on this file. However, if you comment out the lines mentioned above (line 21 - 23), the code successfully compiles.

Is this a bug in the Swift compiler? Should I submit a bug report? Also, for now, what can I do to achieve the equivalent?

P.S.

Meaning of "The equivalent":

`Operation` is a protocol. Some classes that conform to the protocol also conform to `CustomStringConvertible`. I want to check if `operation` conforms to `CustomStringConvertible` so that I can add the `description` of the operation to the `helpString`.

Comment: I suspect it is the unescaped "" inside the literal string. Rather than using string interpolation for the NSLocalizedString, just concatenate it using "+" or use String.format

Comment: Also why not use `if operation is CustomStringConvertible`?

Comment: there's no need using `operation as? CustomStringConvertible` because this cast operation always success. And here's problem, I only write `op is/as CustomStringConvertible`, the build stuck.

Comment: Why don't I need it? @KleinMioke `Operation` protocol does _not_ conform to `CustomStringConvertible`!

Comment: @Sweeper It's wired yes I know. Because the first time I wrote `operation as? CustomStringConvertible` the compiler give me a warning said `always success`.

Comment: @Sweeper I think it's completely wrong, sorry about confusing you anyway. It's sure a bug I think.

Comment: For those who are interested, I have reported a bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1706